# Get Facebook id of person how tagged me on my timeline

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, graph

Currently i'm working on a website for a client.
I want to show his latest Facebook wall posts on his website, also posts he is tagged in by others.
With the Facebook Graph i can get allot of data from the latest post like message, description, picture etc. But i just can't find or get the Facebook id of the person who tagged him in that post... Only his own Facebook id and the id's of the others persons who where tagged, but not the tagger (if that is even a word :P)

Can anybody help me with this?

I'm using /feed in the Facebook Graph to get the data from the posts on his wall

```
$fb_id = 'your-facebook-id';
$fb_token = 'my-acces-token'; // tokken obtained from Facebook graph explorer page

$fb_response = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/'.$fb_id.'/feed?access_token='.$fb_token);
$fb_array = json_decode($fb_response, true);
```

Thanks for your time!!

Comment: Also i can't get or even see the name of the person who tagged him...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you just need to find the ID of a user that posted a status update that tagged your client.

Do things as you were before, by collecting objects from the `/user/feed` edge.  You should retrieve an ID for the status.  With this, make another call to the Graph for `/STATUS_ID`.  This will give you information about who posted the status along with other things.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.1/post

Note that this will only work for public posts with any valid access token.  If the post is not public, you may not be able to retrieve the post with a user's access token that is not the original user who posted the status.  Keep in mind that the docs specifically state:

`Only posts whose authors have also granted read_stream permission to the app will be shown for /user/feed.`

Comment: Ok thanks, that makes sense. But where can i obtain that status_id? I can't see it in the /feed..

Comment: According to the docs, you should get an array of `Post objects` from `/user/feed`.  The link redirects to the `Post` reference docs and it says the response should contain a field called `id`.

Comment: Yes i does, the first field is called id. But when i use that number as the status_id i get an error: 

"error": {
      "message": "Unknown path components: /756073754429126_751126531590515",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 2500
   }

Or that user made the post not public...

Comment: What access token are you using?  A user access token or an app access token?

Comment: Thanks for providing some code, but I need to see where all of the variables involved are coming from.  Please add that information.

Comment: You mean from the JSON i get back? How i get those? (sorry english is not my native language)

Comment: You mean like that? ^^

Comment: Yes.  A couple of things.  You should not be entering an access token like that.  It should come from Facebook in your code.  That token will not last forever and probably isn't valid outside of the Graph Explorer.  You have to have an authentication flow which will provide the user ID and an access token that will work.  Also, revisit my answer which I edited.  Try using just `/STATUS_ID` instead of `/post/STATUS_ID`.

Comment: Ok thanks, i'm gonna take a look at that authentication flow :) Only using /STATUS_ID gave me just that post indeed, but still can't find any id of the person who originally posted it...

Comment: I think you'll find that the first part of that two-part status ID is the user who made the post (not sure if it is app-scoped or real, but I believe its app-scoped).  You can also retrieve the `from` field from the `/post_id` to see the profile that made the post.  `explode('_',$post_id)` should give you two numbers, one of which will be the ID of the user.

Comment: Well the first part of the status id is the id of the page owner, not the person who tagged him... But maybe if timeline control is on and you allow to show it on your timeline, maybe it is posted by the page owner himself and not the original poster who tagged him?

Comment: I would assume its the page_owner as anyone posting to a page is going to appear as the page itself in the post (or just treat the tagger as the page).  If its made from a user's profile, that number should be a users ID.

Comment: Yeah agree with that, thanks for your help man!! Really appreciate it :)